# Java is not able to find a match for regex

Tags: java, regex

I have been trying to figure out why java is not able to find nay matches for this regex pattern, I tested it with https://regexr.com/ and it works fine.

But when I escape it and use it in my class it complains about no match found.

Regex pattern I used in regexr.com
pattern: `TEST\(":"\)\/(\w+)\[@name="(.*)"\]`
Strings to test: `TEST(":")/Role[@name="TestRole"]`
The website is able to find two groups: 1. Role and 2. TestRole. And thats the required behaviour.

But when I use it in my code my test returns with no match found, here are the escaped pattern and test strings:

```
   public String extractCorrectExp() {
        String path1 = "TEST(\":\")/Role[@name=\"TetsRole\"]";
        String pattern = "TEST\\(\":\"\\)\\/(\\w+)\\[@name=\"(.*)\"\\]";
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher match = pat.matcher(path1);
        return match.group();
    }
```

It returns:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:536)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:496)
```

Could this be escaping issue? or somehow I am using regex identifiers which are not compatible with java?

Comment: The pattern and regex in your code does not seem to match your description in the question.

Comment: oopse! fixed it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find() must be called on the Matcher before group() can be called. Your code will work if you change it to:

```
String path1 = "TEST(\":\")/Role[@name=\"TestRole\"]";
String pattern = "TEST\\(\":\"\\)/(\\w+)\\[@name=\"(.*)\"]";
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher match = pat.matcher(path1);
if ( match.find() ) {
    System.out.println(match.group());
}
```

If condition can be used for a single match, and while loop can be used for multiple matches.

Comment: ah thanks! I thought pattern.matcher(String) does that for me.